# VBA Validate that if one cell in a range has a value, all cells should have a value

Tags: vba, validation, loops, if-statement

I have a spreadsheet where users will be entering data in columns A through D. I want to identify in a message box any rows (i) where the range (Ai:Di) is not either completely blank or completely populated. The total range that users can populate is A2:D501.

If no rows are identified, the macro should continue to the next piece of code that I've already written, which then proceeds to save the workbook.

One twist - column C is prepopulated with =IF(A2<>"",TODAY(),""). So, C will never truly be blank. The macro would need to consider the above formula as blank so that if a row only has that formula in column C it won't count it.

Thanks for your help, I'm new to this!

Comment: Should the user input anything to column C? Or is it safe to assume that it will always contain that formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this

```
Function Validate() as boolean
Dim WB as WorkBook
Dim WS as Worksheet
Dim CellA as Range
Dim CellB as Range
Dim CellC as Range
Dim CellD as Range
Dim RowNum as integer
Dim ErrorCnt as integer
Dim ErrorList as String
dim ValueCount as integer
set WB  = ThisWorkBook
Set WS = WB.Worksheets("SheetName")
ErrorCnt = 0
ErrorList = ""
For RowNum  = 2 to 501
    Set CellA = ws.Cells(RowNum, 1)
    Set CellB = ws.Cells(RowNum, 2)
    Set CellC = ws.Cells(RowNum, 3)
    Set CellD = ws.Cells(RowNum, 4)
    ValueCount  = 0
    If CellA.Value <> "" Then ValueCount = ValueCount +1
    If CellB.Value <> "" Then ValueCount = ValueCount +1
    If CellD.Value <> "" Then ValueCount = ValueCount +1
    If (ValueCount  >0 and ValueCount   <3) then 
        ErrorCnt = ErrorCnt +1
        If ErrorCnt = 1 Then
           ErrorList = Cstr(RowNum)
        Else
           ErrorList = ErrorList  & ", " & Cstr(RowNum)  
        End if
    End if
Next
If ErrorCnt = 0 Then
    Validate = True
ElseIf ErrorCnt = 1 Then
    MSgbox "1 Error on Row " & ErrorList 
    Validate = False
Else
    MSgbox cstr(RowNum) & " Errors on Rows " & ErrorList 
    Validate = False
End If
End Function
```

You could also use other functions to validate things further, for example if only numbers are valid for Column D then replace that line with

```
If isnumeric(CellD.Value) Then ValueCount = ValueCount +1
```

Comment: Nice Code. It seems like it would be in order to add a line like --> `MsgBox "Incomplete Data in Row " & RowNum` after the line --> `If (ValueCount  >0 and ValueCount   <3) then` so that the user would know which line was missing data.

Comment: Clif - That might well be appropriate. I'd probably have built up a list of rows to report in the message box just in case there was more than one invalid row but I assumed that this question was really all about how to cycle through rows picking out cells than how to handle the messages so I kept it simple.

Comment: Tom - this is perfect! Would you be able to integrate this so that a message box shows which line(s) cause the function to return false? I really appreciate the help!

Comment: I've added a numeric variable to keep count of the number of errors and a string to build up a list of them you can then choose how to deal with the outcome depending on whether there's no errors, one error or several...